# Looking for a combined Clock/News/Weather/Calendar iPad app

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, calendar, rss, twitter

I'm looking for an app I can leave running and that shows me all necessary info at 1 glance without any need for interaction.

Ideally, it should contain

- a clock
- good, concise news
- weather forecast
- list of my next appointments
- subjects of my unread emails

Other people might also like

- rss feeds
- twitter feed

I already searched for such an app for half an hour and found nothing. Well except for a Dashboard app that was rejected by Apple because it was expandable and looked like the os x dashboard.

There are alternative calendar apps, there are weather apps that show the time, there are twitter apps, rss readers, email apps. Surely somebody has combined all of them?

Can somebody pinpoint me to such apps, or explain why they don't exist? Thanks.

Comment: I might be able to roll one for you. ;)

Comment: Cool! Go ahead!

Comment: Feel free to get in touch with me via email - my info is on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself. There is no such app.

The main reason is probably the rejection of that Dashboard app, which made other devs afraid in losing their invested development time if it gets rejected as well.

Future iOS updates might introduce a Dashboard feature, which might be similar to what I was wishing.

Answer (score 3):

Consider Panic's [Status Board app](http://panic.com/statusboard/): it includes configurable modules for everything you've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a such app myself and so far I've found one [DeskMate Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/deskmate-pro/id464991009?mt=8). Maybe not ideal, but much better than the other apps.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Application has been removed from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Notification Center on iOS 5 fits the bill as you can configure it to list the notification in your preferred order and it floats above all programs running whenever you wish to see the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve some of this without an app at all: put iGoogle widgets for the features you desire on your [iGoogle page](http://www.google.com/ig), then keep a browser window open to that page in Safari in your iPad.

There are roughly a billion iGoogle widgets to choose from, and they include widgets for weather, calendars, news, Twitter, RSS, and more.  You can choose the color theme too.

The main problems with this approach would seem to be that the display of information is not as compact on the screen as you could achieve with a custom-coded app, so it may be a problem to fit everything that you want so that you can see it all at once.  Also, I haven't figured out a way to make the Google search bar go away, and it takes up an unfortunate amount of space at the top of the page (less so in the vertical orientation on an iPad, but more in the horizontal orientation).